# Use Simple HTML DOM Parser to JSON?

Tags: php, json, html-parsing

I'm trying to group each of the elements of a scraped website, convert it into a json element but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php

// Include the php dom parser    
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Create DOM from URL or file

$html = file_get_html('urlhere');

foreach($html->find('hr ul') as $ul)
{
    foreach($ul->find('div.product') as $li) 
    $data[$count]['products'][]['li']= $li->innertext;
    $count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

This returns

```
{"":{"products":[{"li":"   <a class=\"th\" href=\"\/products\/56942-haters-crewneck-sweatshirt\">            <div style=\"background-image:url('http:\/\/s0.merchdirect.com\/images\/15814\/v600_B_AltApparel_Crew.png');\">         <img src=\"http:\/\/s0.com\/images\/6398\/product-image-placeholder-600.png\">       <\/div>                  <\/a>   <div class=\"panel panel-info\" style=\"display: none;\">     <div class=\"name\">       <a href=\"\/products\/56942-haters-crewneck-sweatshirt\">                    Haters Crewneck Sweatshirt                <\/a>     <\/div>     <div class=\"subtitle\">                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  $60.00                                 <\/div>   <\/div> "}
```

When I'm actually hoping to achieve:

```
{"products":[{
"link":"/products/56942-haters-crewneck-sweatshirt",
"image":"http://s0.com/images/15814/v600_B_AltApparel_Crew.png",
"name":"Haters Crewneck Sweatshirt",
 "subtitle":"60.00"}
]}
```

How do I get rid of all of the redundant information and probably name each element in the reformatted json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to extend your logic within the inner loop:

```
foreach($html->find('hr ul') as $ul)
{
    foreach($ul->find('div.product') as $li) {
        $product = array();

        $product['link'] = $li->find('a.th')[0]->href;
        $product['name'] = trim($li->find('div.name a')[0]->innertext);
        $product['subtitle'] = trim($li->find('div.subtitle')[0]->innertext);
        $product['image'] = explode("'", $li->find('div')[0]->style)[1];

        $data[$count]['products'][] = $product;
    }

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: can i ask how to remove the "{"":{" right before "products":[{"link":..." ?

Comment: simply change `$data[$count]['products'][] = $product;` to `$data['products'][] = $product;`

Comment: You're the best. Thanks for your help! :)